How to split logs from auditd rules files
I have a question how can I split logs from auditd rules files for forwarding events only from one of them to remote log server. For example I have auditd1.rules and auditd2.rules on one server I need to send only auditd1.rules to remote server.
May I can configuring somehow rule file and/or rsyslog to determinate events generated from file auditd1.rules?
Thanks in advance!
